# could not load file or assembly 'OSIsoft.PISDK, version=1.3.0.0 culture=neutral

Tags: pi

Just wanna ask,

This error outcome when i want to run using .net, how to solve it?
Please, need some suggestion & answers

Could not load file or assembly 'OSIsoft.PISDK, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3309f0734ba2805' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Put `OSIsoft.PISDK.dll` inside ur development folder,
it will solve your problem.
Happened to me before this.